Tangent and Cotangent space in a Tensor space
$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}$
$\def\pdv#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
$\def\pdvp#1#2#3{\left.\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}\right\vert_{#3}}$
$\def\dvp#1#2{\left.\frac{\partial }{\partial #1}\right\vert_{#2}}$
$\def\df{\mathsf{d}}$
In $\R^n$, if $x^1,\ldots,x^n$ are the standard coordinates then, given a point $p$, $(dx^1)_p,\ldots,(dx^n)_p$ is the basis for the cotangent space $T_p^*(\R^n)$ and $\dvp{x^1}{p},\ldots,\dvp{x^n}{p}$ is the basis for the tangent space $T_p(\R^n)$. Then the differential of a multivariate function $f: \R^n \to R$ could be treated as a map $\df: C^\infty \to T_p^*(\R^n)$
$$
\df f = \pdvp{f}{x^1}{p} (dx^1)_p + \ldots +  \pdvp{f}{x^n}{p} (dx^n)_p,  
$$
where $C^\infty$ denotes the vector space of all smooth functions. Now instead assume that we have a function $F(T)$ where $T \in V^{\otimes r} \otimes  {(V^*)}^{\otimes p}$ is a tensor and $F \in V^{\otimes s} \otimes  {(V^*)}^{\otimes t}$ is also a tensor (e.g. $F=Q\otimes T$ where $Q \in V^{\otimes (s-r)} \otimes  {(V^*)}^{\otimes (t-p)}$). Can we define a basis for the contangent space and the tangent space for a point $P$ in $V^{\otimes r} \otimes  {(V^*)}^{\otimes p}$. If this is the case, can we express the differential of $F$ w.r.t. $X$ using an expansion similar to the equation above?

It's not clear to me what you want. "Can we define a basis" Yes. "Can we express the differential... using an expansion similar to the equation above?" Yes, you can use the exact same expression once you've chosen a basis.

@NicholasTodoroff I am constrained by the perception that tangent space makes sense for a function of a vector, but it is meaningless for a function of a tensor (even if this function returns a scalar).

Tensors form a vector space. Whether you notate that vector space $V^{\otimes r}\otimes(V^*)^{\otimes p}$ or just $W$ makes no difference.
